# ImportError: No module named networkx

Tags: python, contiki

I am following a text file from github to deploy a framework of RPL attack for simulating WSN with a malicious mote on contiki's cooja simulation. The link is: https://github.com/dhondta/rpl-attacks#demonstration

So when I tried Setting up dependencies and testing the framework, by using the code: user@instant-contiki:~/Downloads/rpl-attacks-master$ fab setup

It showed the following error: ImportError: No module named networkx

I tried installing networkx but it is saying "Requirement already satisfied".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you all installing networkx for the correct python version!

Comment: Are you using ANACONDA or something with a different enviroment? Maybe you are using differents python on your computer from different enviroments!